# I want to transfer what I see on iPad app to the PC, is there a way?

Tags: screen-capture, ipad

I have an iPad app that shows some good picture, and I want to transfer some pictures to the PC so I can send them by email to other people.  Is there a way to capture the screen and save it as PNG or JPG?

Otherwise, is the only way to install an iPad SDK (software development kit) so that you have a virtual iPad on the computer and run the app, and then use screen capture program on the PC to do the capture?

Answer (score 3):

Click the Home button and the Power button simultaneously. This will take a screenshot and save it in Photos.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer explains how to save a screenshot (Home button and the Power button simultaneously) on an iPad locally.

All saved images (and only them) created that way are accessible when you connect the iPad to the computer as regular files on a separate disk — the same way a flash-drive's content would be seen when mounted.

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to capture the screen.**

Briefly hold down the "power" button at the top of the iPad, then press the "home" button at the bottom of the iPad which still holding the Power button.  Don't hold the "power" button for too long or it will switch off the iPAD.  you will know that the screen has been captured because you will hear a sound like a picture being taken on a digital camera.

**Email it from your PC**

The picture will be available in "photos", if you have this setup to Synchronise with your PC in iTunes then you will be able to email it from your PC after a synch, normally it will be on your PC in your "my pictures" folder.

**or Email it from your iPAD**

If you want to email it from your iPAD then Click the "Photos" application in your application dock at the bottom of the screen (Sunflower).  Then Scroll to the screen you captured, it will be at the bottom.  Then click the thumbnail, it will open in a preview window.  Finally in the top right hand corner, second from the right click the arrow icon, this will provide you with the option to send the screen via email.